# Can a single image be a positive example for multiple classes?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, visual-recognition

Bouquets of flowers are a fairly accurate analogy for our problem domain, and we have [another S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230675/can-watson-visual-recognition-determine-density) out there asking about the feasibility of a different approach to our problem/goal.

What if, rather than making classes by flower types, we made our classes according to the actions we need to take depending on the contents and complex combinations of the bouquet?

Let's say that, if in the bouquet in our test image, there are:
 `>9 roses, >14 pansies, <1 marigold, any qty of other flowers`
then we need to take, both, *action-a* & *action-d*.

So, then, the same image would be used as a positive example for both class `action-a` and class `action-d`.
Inversely, there would absolutely be positive `action-d` examples which would be negative `action-a` examples, and vice versa.

Of course, even with this simplification it still gets quite complex.
I imagine this approach would need a ***huge*** number of training images.
Even still, I'm hopeful that it might work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have the same image in >1 classes inside 1 classifier, as long as you have >=10 unique images per class AND >=20 total unique images in the classifier in total, including any negative_examples.

However, you should be careful about what you are "teaching" the system by doing this.

Classes within a classifier are meant to be mutually exclusive.  Internally the system is trying to figure out what makes the positive examples of one class different from all the other examples in a classifier's training data.

If the system discovers an exact duplicate of an image file in more than one class of a single classifier , it will use it as a positive example of both classes.  Exact duplicates are determined by the check sum of the image file.

Comment: To add to this: You can use the same image for multiple classes. However you do need at least 10 unique images for each class.

Comment: With the addition of @SimonO'Doherty 's comment, this is now a complete answer to my question.  Simon, may I suggest  editing that into the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on right path. but u have to make sure that u have enough no of images for training and no. of flowers in each image should be clearly visible.
Try it